# Explaining how a decimal expansion must be recurring

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $p,q$ be whole numbers with $1 < p < q < 9$. Explain why the decimal expansion of the real number $x= \frac{p}{q}$ must be recurring.

Comment: $p = 2, q = 5$ gives a terminating decimal expansion.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: You could say $\frac25 = 0.3999999\ldots = 0.4000000\ldots$ has a recurring $9$ or a recurring $0$